# Getting Type + ConstructorInfo from ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, code-analysis, roslyn

I'm trying to get type and constructor info out of an `ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax` element.

I first need to assess that the created instance is an `ArgumentException` or a class that derives from it. Then, I need to get the `ConstructorInfo` (System.Reflection) that's being used.

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(c =>
    {
        var local = c.Node as ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax;

        if (local == null)
            return;

        ArgumentSyntax paramNameArgument;
        bool conditionsAreMet;

        // the code that's required to get both the Type and ConstructorInfo instances would go here

        if (conditionsAreMet)
        {
            c.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, paramNameArgument.GetLocation()));
        }
    }, SyntaxKind.ObjectCreationExpression);
}
```

The `ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax` has a `Type` property, which I'm pretty sure will be the starting point. However, I don't quite understand how am I supposed to extract anything from it.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Here's two code samples I'd expect the analyzer to step into:

Example 1

```
public void MyMethod(string myParam)
{
    if (myParam == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("myParam"); // <--- analyzer should step in here

    // ...
}
```

Example 2

```
public void MyOtherMethod(int myParam)
{
    if (myParam > 10)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("myParam"); // <--- analyzer should step in here

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code you're trying to "parse"?

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, you should use Roslyn's semantic model (`ITypeInfo`).

Comment: What do you need the ConstructorInfo for?

Comment: @Ties I updated the post.

Comment: @SLaks I noticed a `SemanticModel` inside `AnalysisContext` instance (`c.SemanticModel`). I had a look at it but I still can't figure out how to use it for my needs.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I want to know its argument list and see if one of them is a `String` variable named *paramName*. If it is, I want to take a look at the matching parameter passed in the parsing code. If it's a string literal, I want the analyzer to raise a warning and encourages the developer to use the `nameof` function instead.

Comment: @Crono: I've built that exact analyzer + code fix. Take a look here, it might inspire you: https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/tree/develop/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/Diagnostics/Exceptions/ArgumentExceptionWithoutNameofOperator

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Wow, thanks! This will definitely help!

Comment: @SLaks My apologies, I meant the `SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext`, not `AnalysisContext`.

Comment: Look at `GetSymbolInfo()` and `GetTypeInfo()`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Your code helped me get through it, thanks a lot!